# Options Menu not displaying on ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I wanted to display `Menu` in `ActionBar` using `ActionBarActivity`.

I am getting options menu while clicking options button instead of displaying in the top of action bar.

I need the options menu at top instead of clicking the options menu from 2.3 onwards

[image: Here is the image]

My Code :

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setSubtitle("mytest");
    actionBar.setTitle("Testing");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_action, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_item_one:
        Toast.makeText(this, "clicked search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

My XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_one"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_two"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Show your xml of menu.

Comment: I used ActionBarSherlock, so there is not this problem)

Comment: How to get it without using `ABS` Android says it will get by default

Comment: IF you're using a device or emulator with lesser width, items may not show in ActionBar. Try with a Large Screen device.

Comment: if it is in tablet also it is showing the same which works on 4.2

Comment: Try Using, "ifRoom". You have defined "always" for all the items, so system might be looking to fit either all items or none.

Comment: Tried with all those things

Comment: Are you testing this on a phone that has the "Menu" button, like the Galaxy series?

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

Create XML file on "../res/menu/menu_main.xml"

**manu_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_settings"
        android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>

</menu>
```

The option "never" on "showAsAction", important, if you put that the option always show on ActionBar.

Then now we must asociate this option on the MainActivity.java (class whatever you want).

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now that we define the elements of our action bar is knowing how to respond to keystrokes made ​​by the user about them.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_settings:
            Log.i("ActionBar", "Settings!");;
            //open Activity,Fragments or other action
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

If you have morer options on your menu only add item on XML menu_main.xml and on the principal class add other "case".

For Example:

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.menu_save:
            Log.i("ActionBar", "Save!");;
            //open Activity,Fragments or other action
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_settings:
            Log.i("ActionBar", "Settings!");;
            //open Activity,Fragments or other action
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**menu_main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_settings"
            android:title="@string/menu_settings"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_save"
            android:showAsAction="never"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
            android:title="@string/menu_save"/>

    </menu>
```

Comment: The only change here is extending `ActionBarActivity` instead `Activity`

Comment: Yes, change that and say me.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that this is because your device has an options button that would open the menu, so Android don't draw the launcher icon.

http://blog.vogella.com/2013/08/06/android-always-show-the-overflow-menu-even-if-the-phone-as-a-menu/

Answer (score 1):

Try with `return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` instead of `return true` in your `onCreateOptionsMenu` method according to below android document...

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems

As per above android document...

The ActionBar APIs were first added in Android 3.0 (API level 11) but they are also available in the Support Library for compatibility with Android 2.1 (API level 7) and above.
So, If you want ActionBar in android 2.3 then you have to use **Android Support Library**.

**Edit:**

Your menu XML would need to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>

<item android:id="@+id/item_menu_ok" 
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_ok"
android:title="@string/ok" 
yourapp:showAsAction="always"/>

<item android:id="@+id/item_menu_cancel" 
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"
android:title="@string/cancel"
yourapp:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Replace **yourapp** with your app name or any namespace.

Comment: Yeah! I tried with `return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` but no resutlt. I added the library and done everything

Comment: see my edited answer to create menu XML file with android support library.

Comment: If you click on edit question you can see the menu titles that i have kept.I guess its not `yourapp` its `app` in `android:app`

Comment: Please follow up with this link for more details...http://hmkcode.com/add-actionbar-to-android-2-3-x/

Comment: Notice that the `showAsAction` attribute above uses a custom namespace defined in the `<menu>` tag. This is necessary when using any XML attributes defined by the support library, because these attributes do not exist in the Android framework on older devices. So you must use your own namespace as a prefix for all attributes defined by the support library. see [Using XML attributes from the support library](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionItems)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but it looks like your menu XML file should have a **menu** in it. In the menu, add the items. Like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_menu" >

    <item...

    <item...

</menu>
```

Perhaps this works.

There are also a few other things to remember in general. Android decides by itself what to show in the ActionBar (depending on what fits there and other parameters). What does not fit in the ActionBar goes into the overflow.

Comment: If you click edit on my question you can see those lines

Comment: Unfortunately those are not visible after posting the question

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your oncreate()

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.show();
```

This should do what you want.
[Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Comment: I need `getSupportActionBar();` for supporting all devices

Comment: Then just put actionbar.show(); after you initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's try another answer. **If**, for whatever reason, Android decides not to show the items in the action bar, then what your are seeing is indeed the correct behaviour. Items not in the action bar are shown in overflow.

One reason items don't show in the action bar is because they don't have a icon defined.

You do define an icon, as this,

```
 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

and I suspect this is the problem. The launcher icon is of different size (larger) than the action bar items (smaller). Try defining the icon in correct size and see if it is displayed.

http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Edit: There is an action bar icon pack to get you started so you can test to see if it works. Download it and use eclipse to import some icon..

Comment: Should i need to declare in the manifest file.Sorry it is already there in the manifest file

Comment: Huh? I think the problem is that the icon ic_launcher.png is the wrong size. Try adding a icon with the correct size.